# How to cancel a task on celery queue?

Tags: python, celery

I want to revoke a task which is pending in celery queue, but the revoke is not making any impact on the task status. The status is either PENDING or SUCCESS always. Tried celery flower the task status is either SUCCESS or STARTED is shown not able view the pending task. 
Have tried these methods  for revoking tasks

```
AsyncResult(task_id).revoke

celery_control = Control() 

celery_control.revoke(task_id)

from celery.task.control import revoke        
revoke(task_id), terminate=True)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

```
from celery.task.control import revoke
revoke(task_id, terminate=True)
```

Comment: The API changed in Celery 3.1. `from celery.task.control import revoke` no longer works.

Comment: See http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-cancel-the-execution-of-a-task for revoking tasks in Celery 3.1+